# Stata svyset design

Tags: stata, survey

I have to set up the survey design in Stata using `svyset`. I'm a little confused about translating the description of the structure of my survey.

In practice it is a stratified survey. The population to be sampled is firstly subdivided according to the sector of activity of the company (NOGA 2) and then according to the size of the company (`size`). A SRS without replacement was done.
Size is 1 if between 1-15 employees 2 if between 16-50 and 3 if >50.
The survey producer give me the `noga_2` code, the `size` and a variable called `strata` that is built from the intersection of `noga_2` and `size` (in other words it has a distinct value for every combination of the two),

I'm not sure if I have to use

```
   svyset [pweight=gewibgrs], strata(stra_n)
   svyset nog_2 [pweight=gewibgrs], strata(stra_n)
   svyset nog_2 [pweight=gewibgrs] || size, strata(stra_n)
```

or something else...
Any help would be appreciated
P.s below there is the original description of the sampling scheme

Dans le cadre de la LSE, les entreprises suisses ont été réparties en strates selon la branche
d’activité (classes NOGA 2), la taille (en fonction du nombre d’employés : de 3 à 19, de 20 à 49
et plus de 50). Dans ces strates, un tirage aléatoire simple
sans remise a été effectué, puis, dans chaque entreprise, des salaires ont été sélectionnés, à
nouveau selon un tirage simple sans remise.

Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry if I were not really clear.

The lSE is the name of the survey.

As far I have understood from the technical documentation, a given number of firms are randomly selected (without replacement) from a given strata (given by the intersection of the firm size "size", the sector of activity "nog_2" and the region) Information on the strata is stored in the variable stra_n (stra_n could be recovered also by combining nog_2 and size).

Then a varying % of employees are selected randomly from the selected company (the id of the company is also in the dataset "brn_ree"). If the company is small all the employees are selected, if is medium around 50% of employees are selected and if it is large around 30% are selected.

A further complication arise from the fact that for some regions all the firms operating in that area are selected. 
In this case, if I have to work with the regional version of the survey, is it correct to assume that the information in stra_n is not relevant?

I have correctly understood your previous answer For the full surveys I should have:

```
    svyset brn_ree [pweight = gewibgrs], strata(stra_n)
```

while for the regional one I should have:

```
    svyset brn_ree [pweight = gewibgrs]
```

(also because if I write the first statement for the regional survey no variance is computed as it warns that only one observation for strata is available).

Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 2):

I've deleted my original answer because it was based on faulty information.

At this point your question has expanded beyond a specific question about coding in Stata to one that depends on details of your study design and on your analysis goals.  Accordingly, I suggest that you direct it to Statalist. I will only say here that your `svyset` solution to the problem of single-unit strata is not correct.  A good solution will require a multiple-step approach, part of which could vary from region to region.

There is still uncertainty. You use as a stratifying variable "strat_n", which, you say, can be recovered by combining sector and size. Is this description an error? If not, what is the stratifying variable that contains the contribution of region? You refer to a "regional version of the survey";  I take it that you mean an analysis confined to one region.

Before posting to Statalist, make sure that your post follows the FAQ guidelines (http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/resources/statalist-faq/). Pay special attention to Section Three. To get the best chance of help, describe not only the sampling design but also the goals of your analyses.